# Counting number of acidic-H in a molecule

Tags: organic-chemistry, carbonyl-compounds

In a recent exam, following question was asked:

> Number of acidic hydrogen present in X are:
>
> [image]

I've found 8 of them as shown:

[image]

7 of them (marked with numerals) were correct according to solution, but 8th one (pointing with red arrow) was not. Is it because of the fact that the carbon was bridge-headed or something else?

Comment: I guess the trans conformation of the decalin-like ring might not permit the transition from the p orbital to the antibonding of π C=O for the marked hydrogen

Comment: @Yusuf Hasan: How do you know that the molecule has a trans conformation (sic)? Perhaps you meant configuration. I suspect that the inventors of the problem assumed that the order of deprotonation  would be 6, 3(4), 1(2).... The enolate from 3(4) might render 8 less acidic. All in all, it is a terribly constructed question.

Comment: It depends on the criteria used. In aqueous solution, only the H form COOH is acidic when heated by NaOH. The H7 is also acidic, but not in water. All H atoms are weak acids, sometimes extremely weak.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An aldehyde or a ketone with an alpha hydrogen forms a carbanion that resonates to enolate form. This leads to two canonical structures that are in resonance. The example below is a polyphenol compound extracted from turmeric, called curcumin.

[image]

source: Biomaterials. 2010 May;31(14):4179-85. doi: 10.1016/j.biomaterials.2010.01.142. Epub 2010 Feb 23. (https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/20181392)

The hydrogens between two keto groups are most acidic. This is due to formation of two equivalent enol structures stabilized by hydrogen bonding. The structural requirement would be **planarity** of atoms involved in hydrogen bonding.

Below are 3-D structures of the given compound in the question above.

- Structure without hydrogens

Bridgehead carbon is 4. Keto groups are at 2 , 5 and 8 (shaded in grey). Keto groups on 5 and 8 are not in the same plane . Hence Hydrogen on 4 , 22 (see figure with hydrogens) does not form stable hydrogen bonded enol structures as discussed in the above example.

Therefore, hydrogen at **8th one (pointing with red arrow)** may not be acidic.

Note: 3-D structures have been drawn on Chem3Dpro

[image]

- Structure with hydrogens

[image]

- Structure with hydrogens (2nd view)

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your 3D structures, it was very helpful. But, is it true that those keto groups will always be non-coplanar (when both placed adjacent to bridgehead carbon), or is it specific to this one? (I'm asking this bcoz, I'd been provided only with 2D structure)

Comment: @Rahul verma if two keto groups are in two 6 membred rings seperated by a carbon bonded to these two rings , the two keto groups may not be in the same plane.

Comment: Why is hydrogen 5 acidic then? The two carbonyls are non co planar too.

Answer (score 1):

It is because of the fact that a double bond is not usually stable at the bridge head position in smaller fused rings.
Therefore the hydrogen cannot be considered as acidic.

Comment: I don't understand. Where did the double bond come from? We're just asked to find the acidic hydrogens, right?

Comment: You may relate this with hyperconjugation and look into what makes a hydrogen acidic

Comment: Are you referring to the Bredt's rule?

Comment: Yes I was indeed referring to Bredt's rule